# Yom Kippur Night Honour Clarification

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, artscroll, honors

What is the pesicha of Omnon Ken on Kol Nidre night? When does it occur, and on what page of the Artscrol Siddur can it be found?

Comment: Where did you hear about this?

Comment: You are going to need a Festival prayer book (=machzor) see [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=machzor+yom+kippur&tag=googhydr-21&index=stripbooks&hvadid=28036039233&hvpos=1t2&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14165603457242446370&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_5lnx8f3gci_b) It's not in the siddur.

Answer (score 1):

After the Amida on Kol Nidrei night, there are a few paragraphs of Selichot that are said.

The 3rd or 4th starts with the words Omnon Ken - and the Aaron HaKodesh is opened while saying it - hence "pesicha of Omnon Ken".

It's on page 175 of the *[Interlinear ArtScroll](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/IMY.html)* Yom Kippour Machzor, Ashkenaz edition.